# How to use --transform parameter of tar?

Tags: tar

I tar'd and zip'd the following file:

```
/opt/abc/xyz/abc.xml
```

to:

```
/tmp/backup/abc.xml.tar.gz
```

I was trying to untar and unzip to `/opt/abc/xyz/(same path)` directory.

I came across the below command. I executed it as the `root` user, but didn't find any error or output. I am expecting below command will extract `abc.xml` from  `abc.xml.tar.gz` and renamed to `abc.xml_v9`.

```
tar --force-local --transform='s/abc.xml/abc.xml_v9/' -zxpsf /tmp/backup/abc.xml.tar.gz -C /
```

output should be

```
/opt/abc/xyz/abc.xml_v9
```

man page of tar says below information

```
File name transformations:      

       --transform=EXPRESSION, --xform=EXPRESSION
              use sed replace EXPRESSION to transform file names

              File name matching options (affect both exclude and include patterns):
```

Can someone help me understand the above command with some example?

Comment: What do you want to achieve and what doesn't work?

Comment: @Cyrus i hope now my question is clear to you.

Comment: Add output of `tar -tzf /tmp/backup/abc.xml.tar.gz` to your question.

Answer (score 9):

Using your example files source `/tmp/backup/abc.xml.tar.gz` and destination `/opt/abc/xyz/abc.xml_v9`. you can use thsi command:

```
tar --transform='flags=r;s|abc.xml|abc.xml_v9|' -xvf abc.xml.tar.gz -C /opt
```

Or

```
tar --transform='flags=r;s/abc.xml/abc.xml_v9/' -xvf abc.xml.tar.gz -C /opt
```

And you will get

```
/opt/abc/xyz/abc.xml_v9
```

See:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790843/how-to-rename-files-you-put-into-a-tar-archive-using-linux-tar

https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/transform.html#transform

Comment: Additionally, you might want to use the `-P`/`--absolute-names` option, otherwise tar removes the leading `/` *prior* to transforming, which might hurt your transform pattern.