# Stripping and Renaming parent directory for each line output in tar -T -?

Tags: linux, command-line, directory, gnu, gnu-tar

I have an list of directory output from the following command that I want to tar:

`find ./temp -type f -name '*'`

```
./temp/main/randomfile.txt
./temp/main/dir_a/random.txt
./temp/main/dir_b/random.txt
./temp/main/dir_c/random.txt
```

Then I pipe the result:
`tar -zchf ./tars/randomtar.tar.gz -T -`

Combined commands:
`find ./temp -type f -name '*' | tar -zchf ./tars/randomtar.tar.gz -T -`

This will take each result from the output and tar into randomtar.tar.gz

How do I change the parent directory of each output from `find` command when compressing?

When I untar the file, I would get:

```
./temp/main/randomfile.txt
./temp/main/dir_a/random.txt
./temp/main/dir_b/random.txt
./temp/main/dir_c/random.txt
```

I want to get this result when I untar:

```
./new_parent_name_main/randomfile.txt
./new_parent_name_main/dir_a/random.txt
./new_parent_name_main/dir_b/random.txt
./new_parent_name_main/dir_c/random.txt
```

Comment: Does this help? [How to use --transform parameter of tar?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421766/how-to-use-transform-parameter-of-tar)

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, it did! Thank you!!